# How to track *.dll versions in Git?

Tags: git, powershell, dll, versioning, binaryfiles

At the moment we are establishing a local company Git server for a library written in C#.
Our library is full of external *.dlls which have to be included. They will be updated from time to time with new versions.

Is it possible to setup the Git .config file so that developer sees the difference in the *.dll versions while merging instead of binary content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible to do using git hooks:
[Git Hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)

Depending on your needs you can use either pre-commit or prepare-commit-msg which are written in bash and can be found inside each repository in /.git/hooks.
Powershell which can easily read the *.dll version can be used like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
dllVersion=$(powershell.exe '[System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo("YourDll.dll").FileVersion')
```

Answer (score 0):

## Try diff via exiftool or sigcheck

I've set up exiftool for diffing metadata for *.exe files. You can also do this for *.dll files.

It's not exactly pretty but it works.

Here's a little demo in Windows Git Bash:

```
myuser@mypc MINGW64 ~
$ cd c:

myuser@mypc MINGW64 /c
$ mkdir difftest

myuser@mypc MINGW64 /c
$ cd difftest/

myuser@mypc MINGW64 /c/difftest
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/difftest/.git/

myuser@mypc MINGW64 /c/difftest (master)
$ echo "*.exe diff=pefile" >>.gitattributes

myuser@mypc MINGW64 /c/difftest (master)
$ git config diff.pefile.textconv exiftool

myuser@mypc MINGW64 /c/difftest (master)
$ cp /c/Windows/System32/calc.exe somemystery.exe

myuser@mypc MINGW64 /c/difftest (master)
$ git add .

myuser@mypc MINGW64 /c/difftest (master)
$ git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) f43eb0c] initial
 2 files changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitattributes
 create mode 100644 somemystery.exe

myuser@mypc MINGW64 /c/difftest (master)
$ cp /c/Windows/System32/notepad.exe somemystery.exe

myuser@mypc MINGW64 /c/difftest (master)
$ git diff
diff --git a/somemystery.exe b/somemystery.exe
index 2c6fdf1..6137c37 100644
--- a/somemystery.exe
+++ b/somemystery.exe
@@ -1,29 +1,29 @@
 ExifTool Version Number         : 12.65
 File Name                       : somemystery.exe
-Directory                       : C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/Temp/git-blob-a19080
-File Size                       : 28 kB
-File Modification Date/Time     : 2023:08:18 12:55:51+02:00
+Directory                       : .^M
+File Size                       : 201 kB^M
+File Modification Date/Time     : 2023:08:18 12:55:47+02:00^M
 File Access Date/Time           : 2023:08:18 12:55:51+02:00
-File Creation Date/Time         : 2023:08:18 12:55:51+02:00
+File Creation Date/Time         : 2023:08:18 12:55:27+02:00^M
 File Permissions                : -rw-rw-rw-
 File Type                       : Win64 EXE
 File Type Extension             : exe
 MIME Type                       : application/octet-stream
 Machine Type                    : AMD AMD64
-Time Stamp                      : 1971:09:24 18:02:24+02:00
+Time Stamp                      : 2070:12:03 12:32:29+01:00^M
 Image File Characteristics      : Executable, Large address aware
 PE Type                         : PE32+
 Linker Version                  : 14.20
-Code Size                       : 3072
-Initialized Data Size           : 25088
+Code Size                       : 149504^M
+Initialized Data Size           : 57344^M
 Uninitialized Data Size         : 0
-Entry Point                     : 0x1870
+Entry Point                     : 0x23f40^M
 OS Version                      : 10.0
 Image Version                   : 10.0
 Subsystem Version               : 10.0
 Subsystem                       : Windows GUI
-File Version Number             : 10.0.19041.1
-Product Version Number          : 10.0.19041.1
+File Version Number             : 10.0.19041.1865^M
+Product Version Number          : 10.0.19041.1865^M
 File Flags Mask                 : 0x003f
 File Flags                      : (none)
 File OS                         : Windows NT 32-bit
@@ -32,11 +32,10 @@ File Subtype                    : 0
 Language Code                   : English (U.S.)
 Character Set                   : Unicode
 Company Name                    : Microsoft Corporation
-File Description                : Windows Calculator
-File Version                    : 10.0.19041.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
-Internal Name                   : CALC
+File Description                : Notepad^M
+File Version                    : 10.0.19041.1865 (WinBuild.160101.0800)^M
+Internal Name                   : Notepad^M
 Legal Copyright                 : © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
-Original File Name              : CALC.EXE
+Original File Name              : NOTEPAD.EXE^M
 Product Name                    : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
-Product Version                 : 10.0.19041.1
-Warning                         : Possibly corrupt Version resource
+Product Version                 : 10.0.19041.1865^M
```

To get this to work for *.dll files as well just do this:

```
$ echo "*.exe diff=pefile" >>.gitattributes
```

I installed [exiftool via chocolatey](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/exiftool), so it's on my path in all my command line terminals (cmd.exe, powershell.exe, Git Bash, Cygwin.)

I think you can usually use exiftool as a differ of last resort. It's definitely better than nothing.

#### Other tools/sigcheck.exe

Using the same method you could also use something more PE-centric instead. Such as dumpbin or readpe. Or you could do [choco install -y sysinternals](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/sysinternals) and then run `sigcheck.exe` to diff DLLs/EXEs like so:

```
myuser@mypc MINGW64 /c/difftest (master)
$ git config diff.pefile.textconv 'sigcheck -nobanner -a -vs'

myuser@mypc MINGW64 /c/difftest (master)
$ git diff
diff --git a/mysteryfile.exe b/mysteryfile.exe
index 2c6fdf1..6137c37 100644
--- a/mysteryfile.exe
+++ b/mysteryfile.exe
@@ -1,18 +1,18 @@
-c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\temp\git-blob-a11136\mysteryfile.exe:
+C:\difftest\mysteryfile.exe:^M
        Verified:       Signed
-       Signing date:   23:00 2022-05-27
+       Signing date:   03:36 2022-07-21^M
        Publisher:      Microsoft Windows
        Company:        Microsoft Corporation
-       Description:    Windows Calculator
+       Description:    Notepad^M
        Product:        Microsoft<AE> Windows<AE> Operating System
-       Prod version:   10.0.19041.1
-       File version:   10.0.19041.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
+       Prod version:   10.0.19041.1865^M
+       File version:   10.0.19041.1865 (WinBuild.160101.0800)^M
        MachineType:    64-bit
-       Binary Version: 10.0.19041.1
-       Original Name:  CALC.EXE
-       Internal Name:  CALC
+       Binary Version: 10.0.19041.1865^M
+       Original Name:  NOTEPAD.EXE^M
+       Internal Name:  Notepad^M
        Copyright:      <A9> Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
        Comments:       n/a
-       Entropy:        3.911
+       Entropy:        6.315^M
        VT detection:   0/75
-       VT link:        https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/58189cbd4e6dc0c7d8e66b6a6f75652fc9f4afc7ce0eba7d67d8c3feb0d5381f/detection
+       VT link:        https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/f9d9b9ded9a67aa3cfdbd5002f3b524b265c4086c188e1be7c936ab25627bf01/detection^M
```

Like the exiftool way, this also suffers from text conversion troubles, so get garbage like `^M`, `<AE>` and `<A9>` in the text output. (All from conversion between dos and unix and codepage1252 to UTF-8, I guess.) But I just try and ignore that and read over it.